# How to calculate delta between two dataframes?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I would like to calculate delta between two tables (current full and yesterday full).

```
val df_current_full := spark.sql("select * from current_full")
val df_previous_full := spark.sql("select * from previous_full")
```

I make a full outer join between df_current_full  and  df_previous_full  on the key.

```
val df_currentFullTableExceptPreviousFullCurrentView: DataFrame = df_currentFullTable
  .join(df_previousFullCurrentView, df_currentFullTable(key) ===
    df_previousFullCurrentView(key), "full_outer")
```

In order to know if the lines are deleted or created, I can do simply:

```
val df_currentFullTableExceptPreviousFullCurrentView: DataFrame = df_currentFullTable
  .join(df_previousFullCurrentView, df_currentFullTable(key) === df_previousFullCurrentView(key), "full_outer")
  .withColumn("flagCreatedDeleted", UDF_udfCreateFlagCreatedDeleted(df_currentFullTable(key),
    df_previousFullCurrentView(key)))

val UDF_udfCreateFlagCreatedDeleted = udf(udfCreateFlagCreatedDeleted _)

def udfCreateFlagCreatedDeleted(df_currentFullTable_key: String, df_currentPreviousTable_key: String): String = {


  if (df_currentFullTable_key == null && df_currentPreviousTable_key != null) return "S"
  else if (df_currentFullTable_key != null && df_currentPreviousTable_key == null) return "C"
  else return null
}
```

But I have a problem with modified rows ? How can I retrieve them?
I have string, int, date columns in the tables.

Thank you for your help

The code becomes very long if I do 
I have 50 columns and the type are not the same

```
val df_currentFullTableExceptPreviousFullCurrentView: DataFrame = df_currentFullTable
  .join(df_previousFullCurrentView, df_currentFullTable(key) === df_previousFullCurrentView(key), "full_outer")

  .withColumn("flagCreatedDeleted", UDF_udfCreateFlagCreatedDeleted(df_currentFullTable(key),
    df_previousFullCurrentView(key)))
  .withColumn("flagModifiedStringNameId", UDF_udfCreateFlagModifiedString(df_currentFullTable(key),
    df_previousFullCurrentView(key), df_currentFullTable("name_id"), df_previousFullCurrentView("name_id")))
  .withColumn("flagModifiedStringSurname", UDF_udfCreateFlagModifiedString(df_currentFullTable(key),
    df_previousFullCurrentView(key), df_currentFullTable("Surname"), df_previousFullCurrentView("Surname")))
  .withColumn("flagModifiedStringAge", UDF_udfCreateFlagModifiedString(df_currentFullTable(key),
    df_previousFullCurrentView(key), df_currentFullTable("Age"), df_previousFullCurrentView("Age")))
  .withColumn("flagModifiedStringWorkingE", UDF_udfCreateFlagModifiedString(df_currentFullTable(key),
    df_previousFullCurrentView(key), df_currentFullTable("WorkingE"), df_previousFullCurrentView("Working")))

val UDF_udfCreateFlagModifiedString = udf(udfCreateFlagModifiedString _)

def udfCreateFlagModifiedString(df_currentFullTable_key: String, df_currentPreviousTable_key: String,
                                CurrentStringModified: String, PreviousStringModified: String): String = {
  if (df_currentFullTable_key == df_currentPreviousTable_key &&
    CurrentStringModified != PreviousStringModified)
    return "U"

  else return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a UDF for this: if `previous.id` is null, then the row was created, if `current.id` is null, then it was deleted. If both are not null, it means that the row is present in both dataframes, so you can check the equality of both rows. If they're different, it means that there was an update.

```scala
val prev = Seq(Data(1, "foo", "bar"), Data(2, "foo2", "bar2"), Data(3, "foo3", "bar3")).toDF
val curr = Seq(Data(1, "foo", "barNew"), Data(3, "foo3", "bar3"), Data(4, "foo4", "bar4")).toDF

prev.createOrReplaceTempView("previous_full")
curr.createOrReplaceTempView("current_full")

spark.sql("""
  select *,
       (case when previous_full.id is null then 'C'
             when current_full.id is null then 'S'
             when struct(previous_full.*) <> struct(current_full.*) then 'U'
             else null end) as flag
  from previous_full
  full outer join current_full on previous_full.id = current_full.id""").show

/*
+----+----+----+----+----+------+----+
|  id|   x|   y|  id|   x|     y|flag|
+----+----+----+----+----+------+----+
|   1| foo| bar|   1| foo|barNew|   U|
|   3|foo3|bar3|   3|foo3|  bar3|null|
|null|null|null|   4|foo4|  bar4|   C|
|   2|foo2|bar2|null|null|  null|   S|
+----+----+----+----+----+------+----+
*/
```

Comment: Thank you. I have to do this with DataFrames functions not with sql functions.

Answer (score -1):

You can do same way:

```
val isUpdatedColumnUDF = udf(isUpdatedColumn _)

def isUpdatedColumn(currentColumn: String, previousColumn: String): String = 
  if (previousColumn != currentColumn) return "updated"
  else null
```

Comment: I change the question with adding more details